# The C# code generated by WebService missing in previous WebService version

Tags: c#, web-services

Recently I encountered a webservice problem while maintaining a legacy project. The project uses WebService. This is a screen shot.

[image]

You can see there is no actual C# code generated by WebServcie.

But when I created another Cosole project and trying to add a webService. I can see a genenrated code named as Reference.cs, and the content is as below

[image]

Why the previous one doesn't have a cs file generated by WebService?

Comment: The legacy project just doesn't have the proxy service class generated. That's all.

Comment: @ErezRobinson Forgive me if this is a stupid question for I am not familiar with WebService. But How can the web service work if the project doesn't have a generatd class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please view: [Microsoft legacy disco definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cy2a3ybs(v=vs.100).aspx)

Discomap is just a way to reference where the ref classes are, usually at:
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

But that's legacy code.

Modern day .NET have the reference.cs created by wsdl.exe

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have a better understanding.